# Typecheck Errors while iterating through python request response: "len" has incompatible type "Optional[Any]"; expected "Sized" [arg-type]

Tags: python, python-requests, mypy, typing

I am working with request module in python and i need to iterate through the response recieved from request.

**Here's my `send_request` function:**

```
self.query = {"cql": f"type=page and label='{label}'"}

            self.response = requests.request(
                "GET",
                self.rest_url,
                auth=BearerAuth(self._token),
                params=self.query,
                timeout=100,
            )

            return self.response.json()
```

**and the following `get_page_details` function iterates over the response**

```
def get_page_details(self) -> dict:
        """Iterate through JSON response to get necessary page details."""

        for label in labels:
            self.json_response = self.send_request(label)
            results_list=self.json_response.get("results")
            
            # Get page ids from JSON result
            page_ids = []
            for i in range(0, len(results_list)):
                page_ids.append(results_list[i]["content"]["id"])

            if page_ids:
                self.page_details[label] = page_ids

            else:
                continue

        return self.page_details
```

**TYPECHECK ERRORS ::**

> error1: Argument 1 to "len" has incompatible type "Optional[Any]"; expected "Sized"  [arg-type]
> for i in range(0, len(results_list)):

> error2: Value of type "Optional[Any]" is not indexable  [index]
> page_ids.append(results_list[i]["content"]["id"])

What does these error mean?

Comment: There's no static type information available to know that `results_list` is, in fact, a list. You should probably define a `TypedDict` to annotate the return type of `send_request` so that the type checker can know that `self.json_response.get("results")` actually returns a list.

Comment: You should post the function definition for `send_request` along with any type hints, which define what it returns.  You may need to add typing to the `results_lists` variable to match.